# Use std::tuple member references during construction?

Tags: c++, c++14, stdtuple

```
#include "MassivePOD.h"
#include "DependantClass.h" // Constructor: `DependantClass(MassivePOD&)`

class ExplicitSolution
{
public:
    ExplicitSolution() : m_pod{...}, m_dep{m_pod} { };
private:
    MassivePOD  m_pod;
    DependantClass  m_dep;
};

template<typename... T>
class TemplatedSolution
{
public:
    template<typename... TupArgs> TemplatedSolution(TupArgs...);
private:
    // Can assume in-order construction works
    std::tuple<T...>  m_tuple;
};


int main()
{
    ExplicitSolution a{}; // Easy!
    TemplatedSolution<MassivePOD, DependantClass> b{
        std::forward_as_tuple(...) // Forwarded to MassivePOD constructor
      , std::forward_as_tuple(???) // Forwarded to DependantClass constructor
        }; // Hard?
}
```

I hope this example illustrates my problem.  I'd like to make a reference to an earlier constructed `std::tuple` member before the entire `std::tuple` has been constructed.  Is there an elegant solution to this?  I know it's *possible* using `void *` hackery, but I'd rather seek some help before going down that dark lonely road.

## Idea 1

I've tried making a `get_ref` function but I get the same problem that I can't access the member function of an object that hasn't been created yet.  Here's one of my attempts anyway, though.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

class Foo // simplified base-case
{
public:
    constexpr Foo(int x, char y, int& z) : m_tup{x, y, z*5.0} { };

    constexpr int& get_int() { return std::get<0>(m_tup); };
    constexpr char& get_char() { return std::get<1>(m_tup); };
    constexpr double& get_double() { return std::get<2>(m_tup); };

private:
    std::tuple<int, char, double>  m_tup;
};

int main()
{
    auto super = Foo(5, 'a', ::get_int()); // ???
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5805f4ca37601f8e)

## Idea 2

Then I figured maybe I could do something like what `std::function` does with `std::place_holders`, so a static object that contains a pointer/reference to where each element of the `std::tuple` would be.  I think this is worth trying but I have no clue how to implement it in practice...

Comment: Why are you doing `forward_as_tuple`? Does `ExpensiveToCopyPOD` take a tuple in the constructor?

Comment: @Claudiu I expand the tuple's values in the constructor of `ExpensiveToPOD`, and I do this because deducing constructor arity is a really tough problem in and of itself.

Comment: Note that the elements of a `std::tuple` are not guaranteed to be constructed/initialized in the order of the template arguments.  In fact, at least one popular implementation does it "backward".

Comment: @aschepler yes, my wrapper guarantees it for me through using one of the specific implementations that is in-order,  but since it still _is_ a `std::tuple` I left it as is in the question.

Comment: What is your "wrapper"?

Comment: In this example, `TemplatedSolution` is the wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another proposal: the tuple class, rather than taking parameters for the constructors of the members, instead takes functions which receive the being-constructed instance and which return the members. These functions can then refer to the previously-constructed members via getters. All you have to do is make sure that the getters for earlier members work and don't invoke undefined behavior if called while the later members are being constructed.

Here's an example hard-coded for two elements to demonstrate the principle. I will leave it to you to get it to work with `n` elements. Note that essentially you would be re-implementing a tuple here - I'm not sure whether you can do this with the existing `std::tuple`.

```
template<typename A, typename B>
class TemplatedSolution
{
public:
    template<typename AF, typename BF> TemplatedSolution(AF af, BF bf)
        : a(af(*this))
        , b(bf(*this))
    {
    }

    A& get_first() {
        return a;
    }

    B& get_second() {
        return b;
    }

private:
    A a;
    B b;
};
```

Usage:

```
typedef TemplatedSolution<MassivePOD, DependantClass> ClassT;

ClassT b{
    [](ClassT& res) { return MassivePOD(); },
    [](ClassT& res) { return DependantClass(res.get_first()); },
};
```

Because of return-value optimization, the `MassivePOD`s will get constructed right in the `TemplatedSolution` instance.

A fully-working example which demonstrates no copies is available [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2627282667defed4).

Comment: This is a wonderful idea!  :)  Thanks I think I'll be going with this solution!

Comment: Hmm actually turns out that for variadic templates, I ended up needing to pass `std::forward_as_tuple` instead of a fully constructed object, because I had to construct through `std::allocator<T>.construct` which isn't smart enough to use RVO.  Here's the solution I found to work!  (Had to place some of the messy TMP code for the solution to work, so you can fold the detail namespaces WLOG!)  [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fef28978cfdc9f0e)

Answer (score 0):

What about using `std::shared_ptr` and storing it as a `std::shared_ptr` in `TupleWrapper` instead?

```
auto p_first_member_tmp = std::make_shared<MassivePOD>(
    std::forward_as_tuple(...));

TupleWrapper<std::shared_ptr<MassivePOD>, DependantClass> wrapper{
    p_first_member_tmp, 
    std::forward_as_tuple(*p_first_member_tmp, ...)}
```

It is an extra level of indirection, but your expensive-to-copy-or-move structure won't be copied or moved at least.

I was considering why this is never an issue in a language like Python, and it's because the object only gets created once, then everything else just points to it - which is approximated by this approach here. You also won't have to keep any additional track of the lifetime of the object since `shared_ptr` does that for you already.

Comment: Hmm it's a step in the right direction but I'd still like it to be inside of the tuple.  One of the reasons I want the POD to be in the tuple is so that I can get locality buffs; the above case is a very simplified example, in practice I'll have 3+ `MassivePOD`-esque types and many `DependantClass` types that may depend on each other in strange ways, so I'd like the flexibility.  (Types will always be constructed in some topological order so _theoretically_ I should always be able to do this)

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure you can do that. The tuple constructor won't get called until all the arguments are evaluated so `DependentClass` doesn't even have anything to point into yet. How about you make a `DependentClass` constructor which is empty and once the tuple is constructed you call a `.set()` function with the references to the massive PODs?

Comment: Yeah, that's my last resort.  There are ways around this, I'd just really like my constructor do its job without me having to do any extra grunt work afterwords.